# Laravel - Form request validation return empty $errors when using multipart/form-data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, multipartform-data, laravel-blade

I'm getting a problem printing $errors on Blade view. I was using validator on controller/model and everything was ok, the blade could print $errors.
But now i want to migrate that validation to Form requests.

If i use json/ajax (application/json) everything works fine, all errors came in response. But when i use form-data (multipart/form-data) the $errors variable is always empty.

What am i missing? Here's some code:

View:

```
{{ Form::open(['url' => 'foo','files' => true, 'name'=>'foo-form']) }}
    //some inputs
{{Form::close()}}
```

Form Request:

```
public function authorize()
{
   return true;
}

public function rules()
{
   return [
       "id"   => "required|exists:foo,id",
       "begin_date"  => "required|date",
       "end_date"    => "required|date|after:begin_date"
   ];
}
```

[EDIT]

I've already tried many ways to display my errors:

-the official way:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

-With var_dump and dd

-My way (that work with validator on model/controller):

```
@if(Session::has('errors'))
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert_header">
    @foreach(Session::get('errors') as $error)
      <p>{{ $error }}</p>
    @endforeach
  </div>
@endif
```

I've already tested with browser (chrome) and postman too

[EDIT]

Controller:

```
public function uploadFoo(StoreUploadFoo $request)
{
  return "Foo without errors";
}
```

Laravel version: 5.4

Comment: Just to verify, Are you submitting the form data through Ajax?

Comment: @eeya no, i want to use submit form

Comment: Does your route go trough the *web* middleware?

Comment: @TheFallen yes, i am using web middleware

Comment: @AmrAly the form puts it by himself, but, i've already test it adding on form array

Comment: @JoseSilva yes you are right.

Comment: May we see how you called the $errors in your controller and view?

Comment: @eeya i've tried a couple of ways to display errors, 
-the official way : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors
-just with var_dump($errors) or dd($errors).
-Using browser and postman

Comment: which version of laravel do you use?

Comment: @eeya i've edited the question to show the way

Comment: @AmrAly latest, 5.4

Comment: could you please add your controller?

Comment: @AmrAly The controller, at this point, just return "foo" if passes. But sure, i can edit

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set a session in your controller in order for you to return the value you need in your `$error` variable.

```
public function uploadFoo(StoreUploadFoo $request)
{
    Session::flash('errors', array('id' => 'ID required', 'begin_date' => 'Begin Date required', 'end_date' => 'End Date'));
    return redirect('/url/to/your/view');
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@if(Session::has('errors'))
<div class="alert alert-danger alert_header">
    @foreach(Session::get('errors') as $error)
       <p>{{ $error }}</p>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endif
```

Hope this helps your case.

Comment: This doesn't work, because with errors on Form Request (in this example, "StoreUploadFoo"), the function will not execute. In my example, the return string on controller never works (if have errors on Form Request). Said that, if i have errors on validator (Form request), your example of controller will not execute

Comment: What kind of error was it? Can you show us that error message? Maybe theres something about the StoreUploadFoo that makes that kind of error?

Comment: i've solved the problem, was on middleware auth/web. Ty for help :)

Comment: Noted. Sorry about that.